# Why does importing modules result in a circular import error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-module

I have this for the layout of my project:

```
projectFolder /
      setup/
         __init__.py
         setup.py
      Utils /
         __init__.py
         cloudmanager.py
startup.py
```

I am trying to import the `Setup` Module inside my `cloudmanager.py` script (which is nested in one more directory). I can easily import both the `setup` module and the `Utils` module inside my `startup.py` script since it's in the root directory.

I've tried (inside my `cloudmanager.py` script):

```
from . import setup
```

Which gives me the error of:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'setup' from partially initialized module 'Utils' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

and I've tried:

```
from .. import setup
```

Which gives me the error of:

```
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

Any help? There are questions like this out there but they steer towards to using OS, which I'd like to avoid...

Comment: @OsadhiVirochanaJayasingheSi That worked! If you'd like to put that as the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so the reason you're getting an error importing `.. setup` is indeed that you can't do relative imports when the parent directory is a package. A package is any directory with a `__init__.py` file in it.

You could solve this by doing one of two things:

1. You could make sure the *root of your project* is in the Python path and import everything in the root.
2. You could make your project's root directory itself a package and then use relative imports.

## Option 1: Importing from the project root

If your `projectFolder` folder lives at `/home/you/projects/projectFolder`, *make sure* your `PYTHONPATH` has `/home/you/projects/projectFolder` in it. For example, when you run your main script, you could set it before hand. In bash (assuming a Unix environment):

```sh
export PYTHONPATH=/home/you/projects/projectFolder
python /home/you/projects/projectFolder/startup.py
```

You could also do that inside startup.py, if you want to avoid changing the external environment:

```py
# startup.py

import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
```

If you do that in startup.py, the directory of startup.py will always be in the Python path.

Once you *one of those*, you can base all your imports on the relative location of your project. Eg:

```py
import setup.setup
import Utils.cloudmanager
```

(That will work in every file you import after the `sys.path` mutation runs)

## Option 2: Relative imports

If you make your project's root a Python package, you can use relative imports entirely. Eg, you'd have these files:

```
projectFolder/__init__.py
projectFOlder/setup/__init__.py
projectFolder/setup/setup.py
projectFolder/Utils/__init__.py
projectFolder/Utils/cloudmanager.py
```

If you do that, inside `cloudmanager.py`, you could run `from .. import setup` just fine.

## What do you do?

Both of these are valid options. In general relative imports have less ambiguity, since they avoid name collisions, but they're a newer feature of Python so option #1 is more common, in general.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
import setup.setup
```

Comment: Good answers should explain why they work. "Do this" isn't going to help OP understand _why_ they need to "do this"